# Can I force a pre-process action on all commands or environments without having to redefine them all manually?

Tags: macros, compiling, programming, comments, robust-commands

I am trying to preserve a history of the latex commands and environment initializations I use in a typeset html or pdf file.  Is there a way where I can force a pre-process action on all commands defined in my document or external packages without having to redefine them all manually, or run a script on all my files to pre-process the commands (kind of like the way `lilypond` does in producing modified copies of all tex files)?  I would like to declare a macro that is run on every (expandable command) and treats any document command as a string and gives it actions.

I don't think these details are needed for this question, but these actions would look something like:

1. A refname call (not ideal because I think this only works on labels, so maybe verbatim, if this could be applied to the content of `#1`.
2. An execution call
3. Places these together in a hyperref (or some other way to customize the retrieval of two superimposed text objects).

Descriptive Example that won't work

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\WorkContentBlock}{ m }{%
     \href{\refname{#1}}{#1}%
     %refname or other custom verb command to display the command as a string
     %
}
\begin{document}
    Show the latex string of \cite{XXX,YYY} or \cref{label:A}
\end{document}
```

Please note:  Not a duplicate of [Display shortcuts other than urls with href](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258709/display-shortcuts-other-than-urls-with-href) because (while they are part of the same proposal) this linked question assumes that I have successfully implemented the answer to this question or coded it manually).

Comment: It is not clear to me exactly what you want.  I can, for example, create a wrapper to your code so that the log file tells me your MWE used the `\cite` and `\cref` macros, but I think you are asking for more than that.